# haskell: share modules across sandbox(es)?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I did an install of Diagrams, and all seemed fine.

```
>cabal install diagrams
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed: diagrams-1.2
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

But if I try to use it:  import Diagrams.Prelude

```
 Could not find module `Diagrams.Prelude'
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

And:

```
>ghc-pkg list diagrams
WARNING: there are broken packages.
Run 'ghc-pkg check' for more details.
e:/Plang/Haskell Platform\lib\package.conf.d:
    (no packages)
C:\Users\guthrie\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.8.3\package.conf.d:
    (no packages)
```

(The broken packages are all old versions of things that have a good newer version installed.)

It seems to be installed in .cabal-sandbox, but that is not reported by ghc-pkg (?):

`C:\Users\guthrie\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d`\Diagrams...

I understand that instead of GHCi I could use “cabal repl” which would add additional package library references to this to the path, but I want to use these installed libraries from other Haskell IDEs (Heat, Leksah).

I am not sure if this sandbox is a remnant for a previous cabal-install that would not work otherwise, or if the new cabal version (1.22) uses them automatically, or…

I found that using “cabal exec ghc” might solve this, but I tried it, and although putting in the explicit path myself worked, I didn't find the right usage for this:

```
-- Good:
ghc --make Program.hs -package-db=c:\users\name\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d\
-- Fails:
cabal ghc --make Program.hs
```

Also current IDEs don’t have this option.  Do I have to then add a command line option pointing to this directory ( *-package-db=* ) to all other tools that use GHC? and is this the right approach?

Comment: Is this a sandbox in a project directory (ie, same folder as a .cabal file)? If so, then an IDE which integrates with cabal *should* use it automatically (since cabal does so) when building the project. If you are using the sandbox just to keep your global/user package db's clean, then just alias `ghc` to `ghc -package-db=...` - this is what I do. This may not work, for example if your IDE calls ghc with an absolute path - so it would be helpful to know exactly what command your particular IDE calls.

Comment: You can use `cabal repl` to start GHCi with the packages from the sandbox available.

Comment: No, not a local sandbox, one global one in home directory (c:/users/name/.cabal-sandbox...). Windows doesn't have the concept of alias'es - I would have to fiddle with the Haskell-platform installation, and that might break things. I thin all IDEs use direct path resolution of GHC.exe by default. Somehow the automatic use of sandboxes and previous uses of GHC do not seem perfectly integrated (yet?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, IDEs and other tools which call cabal / GHC need to be aware of sandboxes, and behave a bit differently depending on whether or not there is a sandbox.  I can't speak to Leksah, but for emacs, knowing the CLI way makes setting up the IDE easier.

The sandbox-aware equivalent of `ghci` is `cabal repl`.

The sandbox-aware equivalent of `ghc-pkg` is `cabal sandbox hc-pkg`.

It may be worth cabalizing the Diagram that you want to build.  I know this seems overkill for a single Haskell file that only depends on `diagrams-lib`.  I find it takes less time to create a `.cabal` file (or add an executable section to a common `my-diagrams.cabal`) than to figure out how to make all the tools (emacs haskell-mode, ghc-mod, hslint, GHC) pick up packages from a sandbox while building a non-cabalized file.

Comment: Thanks. But this would (will, does) also mean that this use of sandboxes is not backwards compatible with existing tools. Is there a .ghc option which could hide and yet also globalize inclusion of a standard set of installed sandbox packages?

Comment: I agree about the lack of backwards compatibility.  I wish there were more documentation of how to make various Haskell tools work together.  I don't know the answer to your question, though.